# Python: IRC Bot stopped working

Tags: python, sockets, irc

I used to have a working IRC bot, which I affectionately named "shakybot", for it was very unstable in the beginning.

Now, I am recoding it. However, whenever I run it, I encounter a problem. This is the output detected from the IRC channel:

```
NOTICE AUTH :*** Please wait while we scan your connection for open proxies...
:Tigh.GeekShed.net NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname...
:Tigh.GeekShed.net NOTICE AUTH :*** Found your hostname (cached)
:Tigh.GeekShed.net NOTICE AUTH :*** Checking ident...
```

And then it just enters the main loop. It never connects or anything, it just prints this. I am using the same code from the old version.

```
irc=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc.connect((network, port))
a=irc.recv (4096) #Setting up the Buffer
print a
irc.send('NICK ' + nick + '\r\n')
irc.send('USER shakybot shakybot bla :shakybot\r\n')
irc.send('JOIN :' + chan + '\r\n')
irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + ' :Hello.\r\n')
```

How can I make it connect?

**EDIT**: After comparing the debugging messages of connecting to IRC with Mibbit and with this program, I should be getting:

```
Tigh.GeekShed.net *** Looking up your hostname... 
Tigh.GeekShed.net *** Checking ident... 
Tigh.GeekShed.net *** Found your hostname 
Tigh.GeekShed.net *** Received identd response
```

Comment: You should be using twisted or asyncore at the least.

Comment: Why make something more complicated than it should be? If I can do it with solely socket, why use Twisted?

Comment: You would be reinventing a wheel that you don't have to reinvent, as a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `Greg` says is correct. Kindly look into this code(http://code.activestate.com/recipes/299411-connect-to-an-irc-server-and-store-messages-into-a/)  according to `RFC1459` you need to check for `PING` message.

You can also look into the some of the python IRC libraries.
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lalita/0.1.1
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/irc/1.1

Don't forget to search in pypi(http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=irc&submit=search)

Comment: It's not the PING/PONG thing that's messing me up, it's the fact that the IRC server won't recieve my nickname and user info.

Comment: I've tried time.sleep(3), 3.5, 4, 2, 2.5, lots of arbritrary values to wait, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: receipe? You mean recieve? How can I do that?

Comment: @beary605: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/299411-connect-to-an-irc-server-and-store-messages-into-a/ this one

Comment: Yes, that interestingly enough works, although this is exactly what I've been doing in my code, just without the function calls. Anyways, I guess you helped get the code working, so answer for you!

Answer (score 2):

When `irc.recv(4096)` returns, that means you have received *at least one byte* from the remote server. The remote server might not be ready for you to send the `NICK` command yet. You should wait until you get an appropriate message from the server saying it is ready to receive your login info (sorry I don't recall what that message is right now).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following to be a solution for connecting to an IRC Server.

```
    irc.send('NICK %s\r\n' % nick)
    irc.send('USER %i 8 * :%s\r\n' % (ident, nick))
    irc.send('JOIN %s\r\n' % channel)
```